# How can we get the usage of measures and dimensions in SSAS cube?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, msbi, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

We are struggling to find the usage of measures and dimensions in SSAS cube.

**Objective**: To have a statistical dashboard to find the unused or most used measures and dimensions.

I have got help from 
https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2011/06/ssas-usage-statistic-dashboards/ 
to enable the OLAPQueryLog table.

OLAPQueryLog  table provides the following information

1. MSOLAP_Database
2. MSOLAP_ObjectPath
3. MSOLAP_User
4. Dataset
5. StartTime
6. Duration

We are using Dataset field to only find the usage of our columns but not measure.

I have also tried getting the users current sessions using DMX query.

> Select * from $System.discover_sessions

but this is returning me the currently active sessions.

How can i get the historic sessions?

Does any one has solution for it?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you working with Multidimensional or Tabular? OlapQueryLog will only work with Multidimensional (and even for Multidimensional it is probably not the right approach)

Comment: We are working with tabular cubes, do you have any other alternative?

Comment: I would start with using extended events and then querying the results... there is a lot of useful data you can leverage there

Comment: When creating extended Events, I am getting an error "Sequqnce contains no elements (System.Core)"

Comment: It was a permission issue, I am able to log it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, for your help.

I have achieved it Tabular Cubes using:

1. Enabling Event Logs using [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/monitor-analysis-services-with-sql-server-extended-events?view=sql-analysis-services-2017)
2. Using only ***[Query End Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/trace-events/queries-events-data-columns?view=sql-analysis-services-2017)*** Log to get the statistics
3. C#: Using C# to read details of the event
4. By Using *TextData*, and regular expression in C#, extracting measures and dimensions

Comment: Hello Vikas, could you share your c# script that parses the TextData?

Comment: I am no more handling these cases